# How to draw a text in a button

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Does any one know what's the error in this code.

```
let text = "Hi" // text to be drawn

let uiText = NSAttributedString(string: text)  //converting into NSAttributedString

let point = CGPoint(x: button.bounds.midX, y: button.bounds.midY)  //where to draw

uiText.draw(at:point) // drawing hello in that point
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Why not `button.setTitle("Hi", for: .normal)`?

Comment: I need to have different Strokes in my text so I need to draw them. I am basically doing the stanford's iOS assignment 2.

Comment: What do you mean different strokes? What is the assignment?

Comment: this is the assignment link: https://github.com/duliodenis/cs193p-Fall-2017/blob/master/problemsets/Programming_Project_2_Set.pdf . Our Assignment is to create a mathematical game called Set. In the Set game, there are characters that have different strokes. If you go to page 4 in that pdf and read 8,9,10, you will understand what I am saying. The strokes and fill should be something like this. http://www.theboardgamefamily.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/SetCards.jpg

Comment: Right now we don't have those shapes, so we are using ▲⚫︎◼️, which are strings.

Comment: I’d suggest that this is not text. So don’t try to use text. It would be better to use images instead.

Comment: for Set, I would use a collection view with collection cells that either have images or buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this UIButton's method

```
button.setAttributedTitle(uiText, for: .normal)
```

Here's the code (I created two dummy buttons with dummy attributes)

```
    let text = "Hi"

    let attributesFirst = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray,
                           NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.orange]
    let attributesSecond = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
                            NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.blue]


    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.center = view.center

    let button2 = UIButton(frame: button.frame)
    button2.backgroundColor = .orange
    button2.center = CGPoint(x: button.center.x, y: button.center.y + 200)

    let uiText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributesFirst)
    let uitext2 = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributesSecond)

    button.setAttributedTitle(uiText, for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(button)

    button2.setAttributedTitle(uitext2, for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(button2)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVzK8.png)